# Excel: Signing Excel Macro's to prevent "Enable Macros" popup

Tags: excel, vba, security, automation

I would like to know how I can achieve the following:

1. Have Excel open without the request to "Enable Macros" for an Excel sheet that is distributed as a template and filled in by many, to then come back to a script of mine that wants to read the contents of the Excel sheet (Macros are only there for the users).
2. Any actions that require me to perform a change to my own installation of Excel (such as adding the file to the trusted docs), won't work, since the computer that runs the script, can be any of a 1000 computers that contains the automated script.
3. Signing the Excel sheet (something I read here, could solve the issue), is fine, but I would like to know how to go about his, when operating from within an enterprise, governed with a lot of security regulations.

I don't have access to alter the trust center settings, nor can I click the "enable macro's" button every time...

All help is welcome.

Comment: If you work in a *"huge enterprise"* there should be some admin who set up this security settings and they should be able to tell you how macro usage is handled within the company and which possibilities you have to sign or trust a macro code. • And if they disallow running macros like you want to then you should follow the companies security guidelines instead of trying to get around them.

Comment: PEH, the question is not about how to get around the security put in place. I was merely asking for other ways than the ones I mentioned. My goal is to find out how I can work with the security team, to make this specific file safe to use, since it's flowing in- and out of the company network. Integrity should be checked somehow, which implies that trusting this file is not a solution.

Comment: If by *"Integrity should be checked"* you mean the integrity of the VBA code only (not the data in the sheet), then just [sign that code](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Digitally-sign-your-macro-project-956e9cc8-bbf6-4365-8bfa-98505ecd1c01) and lock your VBA code with a password. If someone outside the company changes the code the certificate signing becomes invalid and macros won't run. Your security admins should provide you a code signing certificate of your company.

Comment: Hi PEH, that's exactly what I'm after here. I would like to know how IT can provision this. I tried finding instructions to do so, but cannot find anything. Any useful links you can share?

Comment: This is just too broad to answer how your company can provide you a code signing certificate, this depends how the company's security and certificate handling is built up. So this depends on your company's own rules. Tell them you need a certificate that is trusted within the company to sign your VBA code. They will know what to do (it's their profession) and provide you a certificate or the will sign the code for you (if they cannot provide one for security reasons). It's the task of the security team to provide you the certificate not your task to tell them how (they know how).

Comment: I agree with you, only problem here is that an assumption is made that IT knows how to do it, which they don't. Therefore it wouldn't hurt to arm yourself with the knowledge, just in case they want to solve the issue together with the person who found the solution to the problem in the first place. A matter of increasing your chances of having the preferred solution put in place. Thanks anyway, I think I have all the info I had here and will close the topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution is to store the template in a "Trusted Location" - that is a folder on your network where macros are allowed. You can either set the template's current location as trusted, or move the template into an existing trusted location. Your IT dept should be able to set up such a location if they don't already have one enabled in people's profiles. You'll have to talk to your IT dept because it's unlikely your users can alter this setting themselves.

Comment: Talking to the IT dept is the goal, once I have a viable solution. Adding to the above is the fact that the file flows in and out of the company network, therefore some mechanism such as a signature on the macro would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

Fortunately noone can do this. If it was allowed to automatically prevent the "Enable Macros" security warning pop-up, this would have been a **huge** security issue:

[image]

However, you may contact the people using the template and ask them to enable all macros from the Trust Centre:

[image]

This is how to navigate to the Trust Centre in Excel:

- Microsoft Office Button
- Excel Options
- Trust Center
- Trust Center Settings
- Macro Settings

[Enable or disable macros in Office files](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/enable-or-disable-macros-in-office-files-12b036fd-d140-4e74-b45e-16fed1a7e5c6)

Comment: My requirements exclude this as a solution, since the file won't be the same and I won't have the possibility to trust every single copy of the file...

Answer (score 1):

Vityata's solution only works if your enterprise security policy allows trusting network drives. It doesn't work in our environment as our security policy disables trusting network drives.

I handled the issue on a much smaller scale by self-signing the macros and installing my cert on the client's computers. I only have a few clients that use the scripts I write so it's not a big deal for me.

However, to do this at scale would require your IT dept to distribute your cert via their Windows update mechanism.  You have to have admin access to your machine and a second as a test platform for this to work.

The steps you would take would be:

1. Create your self-signed cert.
2. Sign the macro.
3. Test it works on another machine by installing your cert on the other machine and running the macro.
4. Send the cert to your IT dept for them to distribute.
5. Send the spreadsheet to your clients.

I'm working on an alternative approach of setting our department up as a certificate authority and issuing properly signed certs internally for our own use. We have a plethora of devices that don't have fully qualified domain names assigned to them because the network group doesn't want to deal with the overhead of maintaining thousands of certs.  As you might imagine, it's a project to get all the pieces in play so that one person can handle it.